# Dynamical formulation of the 2-Wasserstein distance for *discrete* matrix-valued measures

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory, convex-optimization, matrix-theory, gradient-flows

**TL;DR: I want to find a definition generalizing "$t \mapsto \frac{1}{m} \sum_{k = 1}^{m} \delta_{x_k(t)}$ is a Wasserstein gradient flow" to matrix-valued probability measures.**

Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space with Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\Sigma$. For real (or complex) symmetric / Hermitian $N \times N$ matrix-valued measures $u \in \mathbb{M}(\Theta; S^N)$ generalizations of Wasserstein-2 gradient flows have been proposed, e.g. in

- [On Optimal Transport of Matrix-Valued Measures by Brenier and Vorotnikov](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/10.1137/19M1274857) (see especially the bottom of p. 23) (only done for $X = \mathbb R^d$) seems the most pertinent to my question.
- In [Melchior Wirth's PhD thesis "Entropic gradient flow structure of quantum Markov semigroups"](https://www.db-thueringen.de/receive/dbt_mods_00047950) in a very general setting of operator algebras. But in Remark 3.14 it is stated that the obtained analogue of the Wasserstein distance is only defined on the densities. Furthermore, it is claimed elsewhere in the dissertation that a weak formulation is difficult to obtain.
- ["An Analog of the 2-Wasserstein Metric in Non-Commutative Probability Under Which the Fermionic Fokker–Planck Equation is Gradient Flow for the Entropy" by Eric A. Carlen and Jan Maas](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00220-014-2124-8), but I don't understand how (or if) the case of matrix-valued measures is a special case of the Clifford algebras considered there.
- ["Matrix Optimal Mass Transport: A Quantum Mechanical Approach" by Yongxin Chen, Tryphon T. Georgiou, Allen Tannenbaum](https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.03041), but again here only matrix-valued distributions are considered (see also the overview paper ["Wasserstein Geometry of Quantum States and
  Optimal Transport of Matrix-Valued Measures" by Yongxin Chen, Tryphon T. Georgiou, and Allen Tannenbaum](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/978-3-319-67068-3_10.pdf)).
- ["Quantum Optimal Transport for Tensor Field Processing" by Gabriel Peyré, Lenaïc Chizat, François-Xavier Vialard, Justin Solomon](https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.08731), where only a entropy-regularized Wasserstein-2 distance between discrete real positive semidefinite matrix-valued measures is defined, but maybe this can give a gradient flow definition?

If I understand correctly, those gradient flows are only defined for densities / matrix-valued probability distributions.
I am interested if there is a weak formulation of the Lindblad equation (the non-commutative analog of the continuity equation) available such that one can also give meaning to

> "$t \mapsto \frac{1}{m} \sum_{k = 1}^{m} P_k(t) \delta_{\{ \phi_k(t) \}}$, where $\phi_k \colon [0, T] \to X$ and $P_k \colon [0, T] \to S^N$, is a Wasserstein-2 gradient flow for a functional on $\mathbb{M}(X; S^N)$".

*Note.* There are different definitions of what a matrix-valued probability measure should be. After taking a peak at non-commutative probability I assume that they should be the state space of the C$^*$ algebra of matrix-valued measures, but I am note sure about that.

---

The very particular case I am interested in is finding a matrix-valued generalization of the following: let $\Theta \subset \mathbb R^d$ be a closed manifold, $R \colon F \to \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$ be a convex smooth loss function on a Hilbert space $F$, $\phi \colon \mathcal \Theta \to F$ also smooth, $\lambda > 0$ and $\Omega := \Theta \times \mathbb R_{\ge 0}$.
I am now interested in Wasserstein gradient flows of
$$
F(\mu) := R \left( \int_{\Omega} h(r) \phi(\theta) \text{d}{\mu}(r, \theta)\right) + \lambda \int_{\Omega} h(r) \text{d}{\mu}(r, \theta)
$$
of the form
$$
\mu_t := \frac{1}{m} \sum_{k = 1}^{m} \delta_{\big\{ \big(r_k(t), \theta_k(t)\big) \big\}}
$$
where $t \in [0, T]$, $m \in \mathbb N$ and $\theta_k \colon [0, T] \to \Theta$, $r_k \colon [0, T] \to \mathbb R_{\ge 0}$ for $k \in \{ 1, \ldots, m \}$.
This is the setting considered in Lenaïc Chizat's paper [Sparse Optimization on Measures with Over-parameterized Gradient Descent](https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.10300)